# Android Error: How to prevent overgrown APK file During compile process in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, compilation, android-install-apk

I have run into a issue here that is causing some setbacks for sure. Here is what happened.

First, I was moving some large files around in Windows Explorer. And I Copied a 4 gb file into my clipboard to move somewhere. I later choose not to copy the file.

Second. Time passes. While the file was still in clipboard, I went back into eclipse and forgot about the file that I had in clipboard.  I then clicked on a XML layout file from a different project. And copied that into the clipboard to move to another project.

Third. Thinking that the layout was in the clipboard I then pasted the layout file into the project where it did not get pasted. Instead the large file began importing into the project! 4.3 gigs...  into the layout folder...

ohh noo

So I immediatly hit the X  cancle operation. And everything jammed up.

Since then, every time I compile I have this huge process that goes through.

I have gone through every file in the project and see no traces of the half copied large file..  but the compiler keeps on wanting to process the file..  what a nightmare for sure.

[image: Overgrown APK]

Fix Attempts..

after blowing away the gen and bin I reloaded eclipe and I thought things were all good...  Cleaned project.. it compiled..  perfect..  then made code changes...   recompile .. BOOM.  APK overgrowth and now .... Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

[image: apk file growth]

[image: log messages]

[image]

After the 5+ gigs in growth.. I have come the conclusion that the 4gig copy paste error is not the issue...

like wow.. it will fill my hd up..

ahhh

[image]

Comment: Get your code in an SCM, like subversion. That way when BS like this happens you don't have to stake the livelihood of your code on the IDE. If you had the code in SVN you could just delete your project, and create a new one/check out from SVN. Subclipse is good, for eclipse.

Comment: yes I have my svn setup...  wow. that is another issue with .svn files not matching after I blew away files...  before I tried to pull the project off the svn many times to have very little success with it not conflicting with the project in the workspace.  all good now that I have created it all from scratch again...  so happy I can get back to dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is a not very sophisticated, but it should be quick.
Just create new project and copy all your classes and resources into it.

Comment: It's ~15 minutes solution. As far as I see - you spend at least 1h trying to find "quicker" solution :)

Comment: lots of grief... I created a whole new project and have just finished mergeing everything..  now no class errors or apk explosions...

Answer (score 0):

Clean up the Project by selecting Project => Clean in Eclipse and it will work

Comment: hahah ohh you know I have tried that....I have tried Cleaning.. Restarting... I am in the process of merging to a fresh project...  I am worried that the update caused some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Close eclipse, then remove manually everthing from `gen` and `bin` dirs. Start eclipse.

If that didn't help you, then close eclipse, delete the `.project` and `.classpath` files. Then start eclipse and make sure it can't load your project anymore. Then re-import Android project to eclipse (via New -> Android Project -> select "Create project from existing source".

Comment: I am going to try :) I will be back

Comment: I tried to do both methods first the gen/bin and then I did the Re-Import but after every single re-import the project was not integrated into a android project...  The nature tag in the .project file seemed to have no entries...  I found it time effective to plow away at the source files that I created and just reintegrate them from a clean fresh new project with no importing from old source...  great answer.. though.